# Jenkins fails to download JDK from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jenkins

I've been trying to build a Maven project using Jenkins for a couple of days now.

However it keeps failing to download the JDK from Oracle.

It keeps giving me the following error message:

> Installing JDK jdk-8u45-oth-JPR Downloading JDK from
>   http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
>   Downloading 5307bytes Installing
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh [JDK] $
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh -noregister
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 1:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open html: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 2:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open head: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 3:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open title: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 3:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: Request: not found
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 4:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open META: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 5:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open link: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 6:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open link: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 7:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh:  : not found
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 8:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open body: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 9:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open div: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 10:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open table: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 11:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: cannot open tr: No
>   such file /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: 12:
>   /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/jdk.sh: Syntax error:
>   redirection unexpected ERROR: Failed to install JDK. Exit code=2
>   Retrying after 10 seconds

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

with which command/tool do you try to download? When I try the link in the browser I get the information: 
*In order to download products from Oracle Technology Network you must agree to the OTN license terms.*

Normally you have to check a checkbox on the Oracle site before you can download the JDK.

When using wget you could add the following arguments to your request:

```
--nocookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
```

When using a different tool, set the cookie accordingly.

Comment: We're using the Jenkins Web Interface to run our build process.
Is there another way to agree to the OTN license terms?

Comment: I just checked a Jenkins installation I am working with. In the section where the JDKs are configured, when choosing to install from java.sun.com there is a checkbox to agree to the license agreement, so this should work.

Comment: I already checked this box, makes no real difference to our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "YUM install java".

Use this : 
yum search java | grep 'java-'.

After setting inside Jenkins environment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: First you will install java on your machine. Second setting of jenkins. Don't use auto install.https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages864759.png

Answer (score 0):

If your using Ubuntu try below.

This is known bug currently. Please follow below steps to solve it.

SSH to jenkins and run below command.

sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk -y

Login to Jenkins

Go to Manage Jenkins => Global Tool Configuration

Click on JDK Installation => Click on Red Cross mark on the right to remove Any JDK you have

Click on Add JDK => uncheck Install automatically option

In name add below line

OracleJDK8

In JAVA_HOME add below line and save.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64